# Does anyone recognize this LEGO piece? 2 studs, big curved section past a hole

Tags: part-identification

I have searched through Rebrickable and Bricklink and can't seem to find this part.  Does anyone know what it is or what set it is from?

[image: Lego with 2 studs]

Comment: Have you looked at the bottom? Try to find a very small number there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

50948 [Wedge 4 x 3 Cut Back with Cutout, 2 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50948)

[ATR 4 (8657)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8657-1) set is the only to include this element in [Light Bluish Gray](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50948&colorID=86&in=A)

[image]

Comment: In that color, it might only be in one set: <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8657-1>

Comment: Hope you don't mind me adding set you've mentioned into your answer.

Comment: Can you teach us how you find this? Is there a lookup function or a description bot somewhere, or did you know the piece, or did you just examine them all one by one?

Comment: I tried a variety of google image searches; Based on my browser history from earlier, the one that finally worked was "bricklink curved cutout". I recognize this piece (I don't have it in this color) but I couldn't spot on any builds I can easily lay my hands on, and I think I stored it in a place that is a bit hard to get to at the moment, so I just googled a few things until it worked.